# How to read attributes from another model in Rails

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I still would consider myself new to Rails. I'm implementing a SMS feature in Rails app that reminds clients of their upcoming appointments. My question is, I have the SMS method in my appointment model, but my client model is where the phone attribute is located. How do I call my phone attribute from the appointment model.

Here is my appointment model

```
class Appointment < ApplicationRecord
  enum status: { confirmed: 0, rescheduled: 1, cancelled: 2}
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :client
  validates :start_time, presence: true
  validates :end_time, presence: true

  after_create :reminder

  def reminder
    @twilio_number = ENV['TWILIO_NUMBER']
    account_sid = ENV['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']
    @client = Twilio::REST:Client.new account_sid, ENV['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']
    time_str = ((self.start_time).localtime).strftime("%I:%M%p on %b. %d, %Y")
    reminder = "Hi #{client.name}. Just a reminder that you have an appointment coming up at #{time_str}."
    message = @client.api.account(account_sid).messages.create(
      :from => @twilio_number,
      :to => client.phone_number,
      :body => reminder,
    )
  end
```

My client model

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :users, through: :appointments

  scope :clients_by, ->(user) { where(user_id: user.id) }
end
```

Based on my current associations setup. In the reminder variable couldn't I just call

```
reminder = "Hi #{client.name}.?
```

And for

```
:to => client.phone_number
```

to access the phone_number attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Yes your assumption is correct, you can just call `client.<attribute>`.

However, be aware of the dreaded SELECT N+1 issue. So let's say you do something like

```
Appointment.all.each do {|a| a.reminder }
```

If you have 50 appointments, this results in 51 calls to the database, one call to load all the appointments and then a bunch of calls to load each client one by one.

To avoid this issue, you can make use of `includes`, `eager_loads`, or `preload` which all load the associated data more efficiently than individual queries.

The difference between those three methods is covered very well in this article http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2017/01/24/activerecord-includes-vs-joins-vs-preload-vs-eager_load-when-and-where. I've quoted a TL;DR excerpt below.

> I'd roughly summarize my approach to these methods like this:
>      If I'm just filtering, use joins.
>       If I'm accessing relationships, start with includes.
>       If includes is slow using two separate queries, I'll use eager_load to force a single query and compare performance.
>
> There are many edge cases when accessing relationships via ActiveRecord. Hopefully this is enough to prevent some of the more basic performance deadends when using joins, includes, preload, and eager_load.

Following the advice of that article, we'd rewrite my example as

```
Appointment.all.includes(:client).each do {|a| a.reminder }
```

Comment: I just saw this. Thanks for your help Andrew!